# Is possible to use ViewHolder with fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

My main doubt is: How can I implement a ViewHolder when I am using fragments (FragmentPagerAdapter)? This is my only doubt, I can not inflate or getTag() from a View, because my fragment class does not have a View object.

If necessary, I can post the classes, but I just need a little example. I deleted the post with the classes, it was too long and would be confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `ViewHolder` when using fragment.

Whatever you are trying to by using `ViewHolder` you can do it in fragment itself.

in `onCreateView` of fragment before return view you can call `findViewByID` for all the layout elements and set the references in fragment it self.

Then write a function that takes your domain(bean object) as input and sets all those UI elements.

The purpose of fragments is to make independent and reusable components so try reduce as much dependency as possible.